# Why is the method executed last always faster?

Tags: java, performance

I am learning about Binary Search Trees, and want to compare the performance of two insertion methods(basic concept is same but there is a little difference in implementation).

I stored time(in nanoseconds) before and after calling the methods and printed the difference. This way, the time required for executing the method called first is always more even when the sequence of calling the methods is reversed.

Common Code :-

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int[] terms = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
BST tree = new BST();
```

**Procedure 1** :-

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
Arrays.stream(terms).forEach(tree::insert);
long t2 = System.nanoTime();
tree = new BST();
long t3 = System.nanoTime();
Arrays.stream(terms).forEach(tree::insert1);
long t4 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("insert ->" + (t2 - t1) + "\ninsert1->" + (t4 - t3));
```

**Procedure 2** :-

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
Arrays.stream(terms).forEach(tree::insert1);
long t2 = System.nanoTime();
tree = new BST();
long t3 = System.nanoTime();
Arrays.stream(terms).forEach(tree::insert);
long t4 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("insert1->" + (t2 - t1) + "\ninsert ->" + (t4 - t3));
```

**Input** :- `12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 90`
**Output**
Procedure 1 :-
`insert ->2155125`
`insert1->431351`
Procedure 2 :-
`insert1->2608819`
`insert ->546649`

How can I correct this problem?

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java), your current code doesn't warm up the JVM. Convert code to JMH and ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know much about the problem so could not find the other question while searching before posting this.